# How can i create a phone number validation in ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, mobile, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to create a phone number validation in `ionic 2` and i've find an  example [intlpnIonic](https://github.com/pierre-vigier/intlpnIonic) but it created in `ionic 1`. so i want like below image: [image]

So My Question : **How can i create a phone validation like image?.**

Answer (score 3):

Best method you can check it here

http://www.moodycoder.com/custom-validator-method/

also you can check below code

```
static isValidMobile(control: FormControl): any {

    let regExp = /^[0-9]{10}$/;

    if (!regExp.test(control.value)) {
        return {"invalidMobile": true};
    }
    return null;
}
```

it works like a charm for me...

Answer (score 2):

i've used third party library named [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input).

**1- First install jQuery**

```
npm install --save jquery
```

Now, within any of the app files import `jquery` like

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

and it will using like

```
$('#elemId').width();
```

**2- install intl-tel-input library**

```
npm install intl-tel-input --save
```

Now, within any of the app files import `int-tel-input` like

```
import 'intl-tel-input';
```

and using like below:

```
ngOnInit(): any {
    let telInput = $("#elemtId");
    let output = $("#output");

    telInput.intlTelInput();
    // listen to "keyup", but also "change" to update when the user selects a country
    telInput.on("keyup change", function() {
      var intlNumber = telInput.intlTelInput("getNumber");
      if (intlNumber) {
        output.text("International: " + intlNumber);
      } else {
        output.text("Please enter a number below");
      }
    });
  }
```

**home.html**

```
<p id="output">Please enter a number below</p>
<input id="elemtId" type="tel">
```

**ionic info**

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.12.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

Comment: I have tried this in my ionic2 version but its not working. Is this the correct way to add this in ionic2 ?

Comment: @Optimus yes it's correct and working fine in my project.